# API Feed and "magic" description and image

Tags: facebook, api, feed

I'm trying to send post using API feed. I set fields: **message**, **link** and **name** - example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed?access_token=XXX&message=test&link=http%3A%2F%2Fsamplelink&name=SampleName'
```

I don't set fields **description** and **image**, but in my post on the wall/timeline I see description (taken from "description" meta tag on the linked page?) and picture (sometimes - I really don't know why sometimes it appears and sometimes not - for the similar links).

Could you tell me from where the picture is taken?
And am I right that description is taken from meta tag?

One more question - how to refresh linked page (it seams to be cached - even if I change description or picture it use the previous one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you post story in `feed` containing `link` field and not providing `description` and/or `image` explicitly it'll be taken from OpenGraph meta tags on the page referred in `link`.

If `og:image` tag isn't present Facebook Linter will try to extract it from one of the images in the page content.

To update OpenGraph cache you should use [URL Debugger (aka Linter)](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)

Comment: Is there any rule how the image is selected?

Comment: @Mag. The rule actually exists: if you want specific image to appear in the story use this as `og:image` (it's actually required OpenGraph tag), otherwise results may be unexpected...

Comment: Thanks, I hoped that there are some rules (I'm only advisor in this case and don't have possibility to change code myself).

Comment: And do you know if it is possible to refresh page -> use updated tags? Why Facebook still use data from the first time this link was used?

Comment: @MagSz, The data is cached, the link to URL debugger I've provided in answer serves couple of needs: 1. check issues with OpenGraph objects. 2. Re-fetch updated data for OpenGraph objects. If your data is changed and Facebook not yet came to crawl your page cached information will be used unless crawled automatically or passed to URL Debugger.

Comment: @MagSz, General advice is: "Use required OpenGraph tags if you wan't content to appear correctly on Facebook"

Comment: Thank you - I'll pass it on :)